# How to vertically center the link button?

Tags: html, css

can someone help, how to vertically center the link button in to the div. The link button height and Menu bar height must the same. If I add text-align :center css style also the contents are not aligned

https://plnkr.co/edit/iV0swyC2VTmAuDTL?open=lib%2Fscript.js

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


</head>

<body>

  <!-- Top navigation -->
  <div class="topnav">

    <!-- Centered link -->
    <div class="topnav-centered">
      <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Left-aligned links (default) -->
    <a href="#news">News</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>

    <!-- Right-aligned links -->
    <div class="topnav-right">
      <a href="#search">Search</a>
      <a href="#about">About</a>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div style="padding-left:16px">
    <h2>Responsive Top Navigation with Centered and Right-Aligned Links</h2>
    <p>Resize the browser window to see the responsive effect.</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

```
[1]: https://plnkr.co/edit/iV0swyC2VTmAuDTL?open=lib%2Fscript.js
```

Comment: Without seeing your CSS we would be guessing. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to see how to put a snippet into your question so we can understand the problem better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `line-height` equal to `height` of your element. Because of the padding overflowing you need to set different for active and "passive" elements.

```
.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
  line-height: 100px
 }

.topnav a {
 float: left;
 color: #f2f2f2;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 14px 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 17px;
 background-color:lightgray;
 height:100px;
 line-height: 80px
}
```

Comment: While using `line-height` for vertical centering _does work_, it is an old technique that requires the heights to be known in-advance, which isn't always possible. A modern alternative is to use `display: inline-flex; align-items: center;` if the objective is to arrange inline runs of text within a parent inline context (or `display: flex;` for block-level).

Comment: You are right. In his solution, he knows the height so I think this is possible. I don't know if you see his code but he has really complex code and this is the easiest way that doesn't break anything.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer worked. Please see the plunker link  https://plnkr.co/edit/iV0swyC2VTmAuDTL?preview

Comment: No problem. Happy hacking!

Comment: For the next time, maybe use codepen or jsfidle instead of plunker. IMHO they are better tools than plunker :P